# POST multiple worklogs in one JIRA Rest request

Tags: rest, curl, jira-rest-api

I have the following data, hoping to insert two worklogs at once into the same issue using the rest url:

```
curl -u jogbra:jogbra -X POST -k --data @data_holiday.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.myworkplace/jira/rest/api/2/issue/4371/worklog
```

data_holiday.txt contains:

```
{
   "comment": "Christmas Day",
   "started": "2015-12-25T08:50:09.423+0000",
   "timeSpent": "8h 0m"
},
{
   "comment": "Labor Day",
   "started": "2015-09-07T08:50:09.423+0000",
   "timeSpent": "8h 0m"
}
```

It only gets the first holiday (with or without the comma).

End goal is to automate the population of holidays.  I don't see a way of making more than one worklog with one request, so should I resort to using a loop to call curl?  If I do that, do I need to create one data file for each holiday?

I see from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719988/restful-creating-multiple-records-in-one-request) that google has solved this batch request issue with a "batch" endpoint.  How would I accomplish this in jira?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but in JIRA only one worklog per on request: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e795